# "funny that he should say that" vs. "funny that he said that"

Tags: grammar, tenses, should

> It is funny that he **should** say that. I was going to say the same thing

What is the meaning of **should** here , and why didn't we use 'the past simple' instead of should in this sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

In object clauses after the expressions of pleasure, displeasure, surprise and regret the so-called emotional SHOULD is used. It is used for emotional colouring and may be replaced by the verb in the indicative mood. The rules of the sequence of tenses are not observed in the former case. So you may  use either said or should say depending on your relation to the situation.